# Typo3 - Different constant value to different menu items

Tags: menu, constants, typo3, typoscript

I want to define a constant variable where I use multiple if conditions to match specific hmenu items(or page uid), so for every if condition that matches that specific menu item(page uid) the content of the constant changes. Then I use this constant in a data-attribute in the hmenu li

Comment: Actually it's not clear what you want to ask. Furthermore you should add perhaps a little bit of code to your question so that it's easier to understand your question and to help you.

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand your question. what is your goal?

constants are Constant and do not change in the process of rendering the page.
and for me it sounds like you try to modify them while rendering the page menu.

what data do you want to add to the li?

Comment: I am not trying to change in the process of rendering. I am trying to have a constant variable "tooltipValue", for example, and its value changes based on a condition that understands the hmenu item id (i guess is the page uid). Something like this: if pageuid == 1 then tooltip=First hmenu item if pageuid === 2 then tooltip=Second hmenu item and so on. Then I use the tooltip constant in my navigation.typoscript where I have my li tag with a data-text={$tooltip}. I hope is more clear explained this way.

Comment: 1. this should be added to your question (please edit it yourself).  2.get a proper wording (not 'constant' but 'data-attribute') 3. make clear what element should get what number (how do the number (/position?) connect to the pages in page tree?)